# Test Class Getting No Code Coverage

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have written a Apex class which is getting called in a trigger.
Now I have written a test class for the Apex class.
But it is not covering any lines.

**APEX CLASS**

```
public class ChangeOwnerClass{

    public static void changeOwner(Quote quote){
        
        Opportunity opp = [Select ID, CreatedById, OwnerId from Opportunity where Id =: quote.OpportunityId];
        System.debug(opp.OwnerId);
        if(opp.OwnerId != null) {}
            User user = [Select Id,ProfileId from User where Id=: opp.OwnerId];
            System.debug(user.Id);
            if(user!= null && user.ProfileId != null) {
                Profile profile = [Select name from Profile where Id =: user.ProfileId ];
                System.debug(profile.name);
                if(profile !=null && profile.name != null && profile.name == 'TriLink Sales & Service') {
                    quote.ownerId = opp.CreatedById;
                }
            
            }
        }
    }
```

**TRIGGER**

```
trigger ChangeOwner on Quote (before insert) {

        for(Quote q: Trigger.new)
        {
            ChangeOwnerClass.changeOwner(q);
        }        
    }
```

**TEST CLASS**

```
@isTest
public class ChangeOwnerTest {

    @isTest static void changeOwnerTest(){
        Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
        opp.Name = 'Test';
        opp.LeadSource = 'Test';
        opp.StageName = 'Identification';
        opp.CloseDate = Date.newInstance(2020, 12, 14);
        opp.OwnerId = '0056A00000264YcQAI';
        insert opp;
        if(opp.OwnerId != null) {}
        User user = [Select Id,ProfileId from User where Id=: opp.OwnerId];
        if(user!= null && user.ProfileId != null){
            Profile profile = [Select name from Profile where Id =: user.ProfileId ];
            if(profile !=null && profile.name != null && profile.name == 'TriLink Sales & Service'){
                Quote q = new Quote();
                q.Id = opp.Id;
                q.ownerId = opp.CreatedById;
                insert q;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Could you please tell me what change needs to be done here?

Comment: 1. This suggests user is null, profile ID is null or the profile name is not as expected. 2. This is not a test since it has no asserts.

Comment: Hi Phil, what should I change here then?

Comment: It is a bad idea to rely on existing users with specific configuration in a unit test; you can have unit tests create temporary new users, probably in a @TestSetup method, and ensure that they are appropriate for the testing you are trying to do.

Comment: You have nested your entire logic, along with SOQLs within the for loop, which is not a good practice. You refactor and should bulkify the code, and then write the necessary test coverage code.

Comment: ok Thanks Phil.